# Homebrewed Python 2.7 pip is not working

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, homebrew

I installed python 2.7 by using homebrew and updated pip by

```
easy_install pip
pip install -U pip
```

After this I was trying to install a python package but I got this error;

```
pip install pyfasta                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2749, in <module>
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 446, in _build_master
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 459, in _build_from_requirements
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 628, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.4
```

I appreciate any help on get PIP working.

`brew --env`:

```
HOMEBREW_CC: clang HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++ MAKEFLAGS: -j8
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH:
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR:
/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.9
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal PATH:
/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbinBrew --env
```

`brew --config`:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew
HEAD: 56ec04a5cfb1bc759a429229128b66d76b44144e
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: 8-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.9.2-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
Clang: 5.1 build 503
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: Homebrew installs `pip` *already* with Python. See https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python

Comment: I know this but I wanted to update pip so I followed an instruction posted by [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html) but this was a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
brew uninstall python
brew install python
```

See more:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1800